# Dialog with EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialog

I am trying to make a `Dialog` that has an `EditText` on it where the user will type and then click OK.

I have not been able to find any examples of this type of `Dialog` (text to speech translation)

Can you please point me towards a reference or provide an example?

Comment: you can refer to [this link](http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-user-input-with-an-alertdialog) for details.

Comment: You should really read the android fundamental documentation to learn.. instead of just always copying from examples. This is far more effective to the process of learning.

Comment: You have "(text to speech translation)" in your question. What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: it means the typos r because it doesn't know the difference between dialog and dialogue...but it looks like stackoverflow corrected it...and @joxtraex i ONLY ask here if for some reason i cant figured it out myself

Comment: Edit your question in the perspective of the people who answer this question. If you want us to study for you, we can't. Googling is a type of research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) to customize an alert dialog. In particular the `setView()` method will allow you to add Views to the dialog, in this case an EditText.

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(et)
.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
        String input = et.getText().toString();
                //do something with input
        }
});
AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
ad.show();
```

Comment: ty too...i normally as for links to tutorials...lol